# How to make a number of breaks in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want the content to be shown like this but without `<br>` tag by using somehow in CSS. Something like this:

```html
Hi <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> Hello <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> Bye
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the breaks? If it's spacing, that's what margins &/or padding are for.

Comment: Text should be in text elements...then it can be styled with CSS. Text nodes cannot be selected with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<pre>` tag if you need to target plain text.

```html
<pre>
one




two





three
</pre>
```

Or, the CSS way `white-space: pre;` for other elements like `<div>`.

```css
div {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>
one




two





three
</div>
```

Comment: Learned something new. +1

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with it. That's a nice usage of pre tag. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these css properties, but you must put the text into HTML tags, such as `<p>`, `div`, etc:

height
margin-top
margin-bottom
padding-top
padding-bottom

```css
#midP{margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<p>Hi</p> 
<p id="midP">Hello</p>
<p>Bye</p>
```

Comment: I know that but it's a long process. I will go with pangloss. Thanks for the reply.